# Looking for an algorithm to determine the difference of reachable vertices

Tags: graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

For a project I need to know which vertices are reachable from one vertex but not another in a directed acyclic graph.

For the graph, the following assumptions can be made:

- Each vertex has only one or two outgoing edges (more are possible but unlikely).
- The number of incoming edges is not limited.
- The graph grows fast in depth, but slow in breadth.
- Basically you can imagine the graph being the relation in a git repository. The vertices are commits and the edges are the relation to the parent commit(s).

At the moment I just calculate the neighborhood (with infinite depth) for each of the two vertices and calculate the difference between the two result sets. However, this was an expensive method to begin with and as the graph grows larger it just becomes slower.

## Example graph (Edges are directed from top to bottom):

```
* A
|\
| * B
* |   C
| | 
| |
| * D
* |   E
|\ \
| |/
| * F
* |   G
|\ \
| |/
| * H
|/
* I
```

- Reachable from **A**: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I
- Reachable from **C**: C, E, F, G, H, I

So the difference between **A** and **C** is: A, B, D

Comment: If you really want all vertices that can be reached from A but not from B then you will have to find all descedents of at least one for them (i.e. neighborhood with full depth) but if you are just interested if a specific set of nodes can be reached from A, B or both there might be a faster way. Also: do you want to do this kind of thing once or many times with the same graph? If you want to do it many times it might be worth making a dictionary where each node has a set of all its descendants associated with it.

Comment: @Chris "you will have to find all descedents of at least one for them" I don't think that's true, because if you know that a node C can be reached from both A and B then you can skip all descendents of C

Comment: @Chris: This will be done for the same graph quite often. But the graph is being constantly modified. It also currently has 1.5 million vertices and 2 million edges, so storing the descendants of each vertex might be a little bit over the top.